# PyMel in Sublime Text 2 on Mac

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, maya, pymel

I want to start programming for Maya and I want to setup Sublime Text 2 for PyMel on my Mac. I tried a few tutorials, but it hasn't worked yet.

I installed SublimeCodeIntel and get familiar with it, but I don't know exactly how to add a new language. The ReadMe suggests to edit the config-file. But what do I have to do now? I assume I need to specify the paths to the libraries. But where can I find them on a Mac?

According to this [tutorial](http://www.dannywynne.com/blog/?p=66) I tried this:

```
{
    "Python": {
    "python": '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/Python.app',
    "pythonExtraPaths" = [
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages',
'/Applications/Autodesk/maya2013/devkit/devkit/other/pymel/extras/completion/py'
]
}
}
```

It doesn't work and I'm totally lost now. I really want to understand this, but I don't even know where to begin.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try SublimeJEDI https://github.com/srusskih/SublimeJEDI , Its working fine with sublime.